# AlertDialog appearing before it's supposed to(Android)

Tags: c#, android, android-alertdialog, behavior

I'm creating an Android App using C#, here is my MainActivity:

```
[Activity(Label = "TestAlertDialogDisappearing", MainLauncher = true)]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        DisplayToasts();
    }

    public void DisplayToast()
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, "Some toast", ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }

    public void DisplayToasts()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            DisplayToast();
        }

        ImportFinishedEventHandler importFinishedHandler = new ImportFinishedEventHandler();
        importFinishedHandler.OnImportFinished += ShowAlertMessage;
        importFinishedHandler.FireEvent();
    }

    private void ShowAlertMessage(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialog.SetMessage("Alert Dialog");
        alertDialog.SetPositiveButton("OK", delegate
        {
            alertDialog.Dispose();
        });

        Dialog dialog = alertDialog.Create();
        dialog.Show();
    }
}

class ImportFinishedEventHandler
{
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> OnImportFinished;
    public void FireEvent()
    {
        if (OnImportFinished != null)
        {
            OnImportFinished(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
}
```

According to the sequence of the code `alertDialog` must appear after all Toasts appearance, but in my case it appears at the same time. Why is that and how can I solve it? StackOverflow wants me to give more details but I don´t know what else to say so I will repeat that sentence 2 times.  StackOverflow wants me to give more details but I don´t know what else to say so I will repeat that sentence 2 times.

Comment: the time required to display the toast 6 times is quite more. The compiler has successfully executed the for loop but the time required is quite more to display the toast. Compiling and displaying output are 2 asynchronous tasks.  hence the alert view appears before the toast happens

Comment: Absolutely correct. there you go, got your answer in a comment.

Comment: How can I acieve alertDialog to appear after all Toasts appearance?

Comment: I don't think that would help. it would send signal to show the toast and move on to next iteration.

Comment: see toast showing time is either 2 sec or 3.5 sec. Try using handler and skip the calling of alert dialog for 12 or 21 secs as per your choosing.

Answer (score 0):

Toast display works differently. Your app would send signal to OS to show toast and then move on to the next iteration of the loop. This is what causing you to see alert and toast together.

Toast showing time is either 2 seconds(LENGTH_SHORT) or 3.5 seconds (LENGTH_LONG). Try using handler and skip the calling of alert dialog for 12 (6 * 2) or 21 (6 * 3.5) seconds as per your choosing. This should be something like this in Java

```
new android.os.Handler(getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        showAlert();
    }
}, numberOfToast * lengthOfEachToast);
```

**Note:** If someday google changes the default duration, alert would get displayed little early. But I am pretty confident they are not doing it anytime soon. So you should be ok.

Comment: I put System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(21000) before AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog declaration but it continues happening the same thing

Comment: don't put the thread on sleep. You would putting UI thread on sleep. Thats not what I am suggesting. use a handler your for loop.